# Export XML filled-up in form automatilly after filled-up

Tags: python, html, django

i'm trying to export a XML to user that fille-up in form in page.html and got 2 problems thats cannot resolve.

Little look at view.xml

```
nomeEmpresa = request.GET.get('insi')
caminhoXML = 'sistema/templates/paginas/geras-prev/previc/caixa/'
file = f'{nomeEmpresa}-{now.now()}'
nomeXML = ET.Element('caixa')
ET.SubElement(nomeXML, "isininstituicao").text = request.GET.get('insi')
ET.SubElement(nomeXML, "tpconta").text = request.GET.get('tipoDeConta')
ET.SubElement(nomeXML, "saldo").text = request.GET.get('saldo')
ET.SubElement(nomeXML, "nivelrsc").text = request.GET.get('nivelDeRisco')
ET.ElementTree(nomeXML).write(f"{caminhoXML}{file}.xml")

for file in glob.glob(f'{caminhoXML}*.xml'):
    if 'None' in file:
        os.remove(file)
        download = False
    else:
        download = True

if download == False:
    return render(request, 'paginas/geras-prev/previc/caixa/index.html')
else:
    return render(request, 'paginas/geras-prev/previc/caixa/index.html')
```

Questions:

1. Everytime the user access the page.html it generate a null xml, because user doesn't fill the form in index.html, what need i do to doesn't generate it without the if/else ?
2. After user will fill the form, it will generate a right XMl file, but it save in sever. How to export that file download it automatilly after fill the form ?

**PS:** I don't want to use a database, because its a simple XML export without any interaction.